# Call Rest API using AWS Load Balancer default DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I am new to AWS

I am develpoing a PoC for AWS server & PC Client COmmunication
My AWS Server App (Running in Ubuntu EC2) has exposed a rest API (RestAPI Name is /TestAPI)

If I call the Rest API in my C# code with "http://EC2 Ubuntu IP:8080/TestAPI", its working fine. I am getting data

I have created a Application Load Balancer & attached target Group where Ubuntu EC2 instance is added as a listner

I want to call the Rest API using **Load Balancer default DNS**
But if I call like below, EC2 instace Rest API is not working
"http://Load Balancer Default DNS:8080/TestAPI"
"http://Load Balancer Default DNS/TestAPI"

Kindly help

Comment: what is the status of health check of your target group?

Comment: posted a solution, which speaks about health checks, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your health check of your target group associated with your Load balancer.

Load balancer will not forward traffic to your instances within the target group until it deems them as `healthy`.

As i can see you are port 8080 for your application, you need to set a health check for port 8080 and you need to mention health check path, by default it is `/`, if you can access your application on `/` then path is fine otherwise you need to provide path which is accesbile so that alb can successfully send packets and verify that path.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html